# Identifying a Specific Face in an Image

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

Using [OpenCV's HaarDetectObjects](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/objdetect_cascade_classification.html#haar-feature-based-cascade-classifier-for-object-detection) with haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml, I've found I can detect a face fairly reliably. However, is anyone aware of any libraries or methods for identifying a face (i.e. labeling it with a name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [PyVision](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyvision/index.php?title=Main_Page). It's part of a research project out of Colorado State University but it's fairly mature. I've had good success using it, though I've never used the face-labeling parts.